# OS X : Use the same local ip Ethernet + Wifi

Tags: macos, wireless-networking, ip, ethernet, local

I currently have a Macbook connected to a Thunderbolt Ethernet adapter and as a backup it connects to the same network via wifi. I' using last years airport extreme as a router.

I tend to do a lot of front end development which means device testing. So my workflow consists of connecting to my Macbook's local IP, which ever that may be, from my mobile devices. I'm trying to simplify things by trying to use the same IP on both ethernet and wifi when the ethernet has been disconnected.

There are a few reasons why I need to do this, but the main one is that my web application stores its url in the database and if I had to change that each time, it would get quite annoying.

Is there a way to keep the same IP? I've tried setting up a DHCP Reservation for a single client ID and setting both the ethernet and wifi to that client ID but that has only worked intermittently.

Comment: DHCP reservation is usually based on the Mac Address. Your Wifi Adapter will have a unique MAC Address, and your Ethernet also have a unique MAC Address. If your router allows it you may be able to set both MAC address to the same IP. Some router may block it due to they are aware that the same IP has been reserved for other MAC address to avoid conflict.

Comment: can't you just connect by hostname?